# How to get the display text and value in angular js material md-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to get the display text and value in angular material md-select. I am able to get only the Model value(selected_value)

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Some Label</label>
  <md-select 
             ng-model="selected_value">
    <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" >
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

My list

```
[ID: name1, Name:value1]
[ID: name2, Name:value2]
[ID: name3, Name:value3]
[ID: name4, Name:value4]
```

I need to get value1 if name1 is selected .

Comment: Is this AngularJS 1.x or Angular2?

Comment: Its in AngularJS 1.x

Answer (score 0):

Like all option in a select field you can bind the **display value**, here `item.Name`, and link to it **another value**, here `item.ID`. So you can write your code like this :

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
   <label>Some Label</label>
   <md-select ng-model="selected_value">
      <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">{{ item.Name }}</md-option>
   </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

When an option is selected, the model, here `selected_value`, is equal to the value from `ng-value`.

Above, the select field displays all the **name of each item** and when an user selects **an option** you can get your **full item** (ID and Name) via the variable `selected_value`.

For more information, you can read the **official documentation** : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.ID'}"` to select `{ID: name1, Name:value1}`

```
<md-select name="serviceType"
           id="serviceType"
           ng-model="ctrl.selected_value"
           ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.ID'}">
  <md-option ng-value="t" ng-repeat="t in ctrl.items">{{ t.Name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```